# dictionary and string split in server

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, methods, split

Hi I am having problem with my dictionary initialization. I have to declare a dictionary and populated with the (userName) and (location) which I am reciving from the client. when it finds the userName it should send back the location if not it shouls send back"no entries found" and if the location is it updated then it should say "OK". Right now i am getting an out of bounds error can someone help me fix it. thank you.

```
protected static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

static void doRequest(NetworkStream socketStream)
{
    try
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

        String line = sr.ReadLine();   
        Console.WriteLine("Respond recived " + line);

        String[] sections = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

        dict.TryGetValue(sections[0],out sections[1]);

        if(sections[0].Length>1)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(sections[1]);
            sw.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            sw.WriteLine("no entries found");
            sw.Flush();
        }
        if(sections[1].Length>2)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("OK");
            sw.Flush();
        }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);

    }

}
```

Comment: What does `line` contain? Did you use a debugger and see what its value is? I bet it doesn´t contain a space, making `sections` an array with only a single element.

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown by the dictionary and not the arrays? Post the full exception. I suspect its call stack will show the error was thrown by the `sections` array

Comment: In any case, this code doesn't initialize the dictionary, it looks up values. It doesn't add any values to it

Comment: This would be a lot easier to work with if you split it up. The logic you're trying to test involves nothing but strings. But in order to test it you need to create a `NetworkStream`. That makes testing a lot harder. Instead, just write the code to handle nothing but strings. Then you can test it easily and work out the bugs. Finally, write a class that handles streams, reads strings from the the streams, calls your other class, and then passes the results to another stream. Short version - don't mix up reading and writing streams with your string logic.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, these 2 lines are the problem:

```
String[] sections = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
dict.TryGetValue(sections[0],out sections[1]);
```

If `line.Split` returns 1 string (say the line doesn't have any spaces), then sections[1] (the second string in the array) will not exist and you get an IndexOutOfRangeException.

I would recommend using a separate variable for the TryGet

```
dict.TryGetValue(sections[0],var out foundValue);
```